# How to retrieve highlighted dynamic map image in ArcGIS rest API for given polygon geometries?

Tags: arcgis-rest-api

I am using ArcGIS rest api export map operation in dynamic map service to retrieve png for given extent. I want to highlight specific polygon (already have geometry of polygon) with any colour using rest api and retrieve png from server. Is it possible to highlight (add graphics) specific geometry using rest api only?

Note that client is in Java and I don't want to introduce any new technology (ArcObjects etc).

Answer (score 0):

I had polygon metadata in spatial database. To solve this problem, I added a new layer in ArcGIS rest services. This layer was given specific colour (RGB). In the map export operation, I passed layer definitions to highlight specific polygons with specific colour (new layer).